# Variable with mDBapi.putfile?

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

Im trying to use the dropbox api to upload a file from a list view. My code is:

```
 File file = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() + "/" + item);
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
               Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile(file, inputStream, //This is my issue
                        file.length(), null, null);
```

My question is, can a variable not be used with mDBapi.putfile? Am I forced to use a hardcoded string? Trying to use my file variable results in:

"The method putFile(String, InputStream, long, String, ProgressListener) in the type DropboxAPI is not applicable for the arguments (File, FileInputStream, long, null, null)"

Comment: Ah, looking at the method signature - the first parameter must be a string so it looks like you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for this call](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html) state:

> public DropboxAPI.Entry putFile(java.lang.String path,
>                                   java.io.InputStream is,

...

> path - the full Dropbox path where to put the file, including directories and filename. 
>   is - the InputStream from which to upload.

So, 'path' should be a string of the desired remote path (on Dropbox), and 'is' is how the actual file content is retrieved.

It looks like you're trying to pass the file object itself as 'path', but instead you should be able to just build the the string for the desired path however you wish (which may include the original name.)

Comment: Holy crap I was totally backwards!!! Man, thank you so much!!! Cannot thank you enough!